# POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found) & axios error

Tags: reactjs, axios, environment-variables, mern

I have been trying to get the response from the server but it shows error. I'm using vs code for this program. When I check the "process.env.MONGO_URL" using console.log() ,it says undefined. (It worked untill yesterday)

and when check the network in inspect mode in chrome, for register page , it shows

```
xhr.js:247          POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:142
httpMethod @ Axios.js:181
wrap @ bind.js:5
registerUser @ RegisterPage.jsx:11
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

The network page shows

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5173/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:5173
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Register page

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react";

export default function RegisterPage(){
    const [name,setName] = useState('');
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
    function registerUser(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:5173/register',{
            name,
            email,
            password
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
            <div className="mb-32">
                <h1 className="text-4xl py-4 text-center mb-4" >Register</h1>
                <form className="max-w-md mx-auto" onSubmit={registerUser}>
                    <input  type="text" placeholder="your name" 
                            value={name} onChange={
                            ev =>setName(ev.target.value)}>

                    </input>
                    
                    <input  type='email'placeholder="your@email.com" 
                            value={email} onChange = {
                            ev =>setEmail(ev.target.value)}>

                    </input>

                    <input  type='password' placeholder="password"
                            value={password} onChange= {
                            ev=>setPassword(ev.target.value)}>

                    </input>
                    
                    <button className="primary">Register</button>

                    <div className="text-center p-3 text-gray-500">
                        Already have an account?
                        <Link className="underline text-black"
                        to={"/login"}>login</Link>
                    
                    
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

index.js page

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
require('dotenv').config({debug : true})
const User = require('./models/User.js')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const bcryptSalt =  bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    credentials:true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
}));
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);

app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    res.json("test done")
})

app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    const {name,email,password} = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.create({            /*User = usermodel   userDoc = user created user*/
        name,
        email,
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password,bcryptSalt),

    }) 


    res.json(userDoc)
})


app.listen(3000);
```

User.js page

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email:{ type:String,
            unique:true},
    password :String,
});     

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)

module.exports = UserModel;
```

it is app.jsx

```
import './App.css'
import {Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import IndexPage from './pages/IndexPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import Layout from './Layout';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function App() {
  return (

    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route  index element = {<IndexPage/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage/>}/>
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage/>}/>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
    
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `app.listen(3000);` <- you're trying to post to port `5173`, but your app is running on port `3000`

Comment: @AndyRay Do I need to update app. Listen (5173)? but its not working

Comment: You are running the server on port 3000, but in your client you are using 5173.
please replace your url to `http://localhost:3000/register`

Comment: @SurajGupta as u said i have updated the "axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register' " in register page ,but still shows an error "POST http://localhost:3000/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: is your server running and remove `origin: 'http://localhost:5173', from index.js

Comment: @SurajGupta if i remove it says ,"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/register' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."

Comment: pass `withCredentials: true` flag in your axios request

Comment: @SurajGupta it says xhr.js:247 POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your backend server run on different port since React runs on port `:3000` by default so change your backend server's port. In index.js of backend code change `app.listen(3000)` to `app.listen(5000)`

Now you can request your API in react as below

> Axios is asynchronous use `.then .catch` or `async await`

```js
async function registerUser(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register',{
            name,
            email,
            password
        });
    }
```

and don't forget to configure cors `app.use(cors())` in index.js

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running your server on port 3000, But in your client you are using port 5173 to post your request.

To make it work, you need to post your register request on `localhost:3000/register` and pass withCredentials flag true along with you request

index.js

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
require('dotenv').config({debug : true})
const User = require('./models/User.js')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const bcryptSalt =  bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    credentials:true
}));
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);

app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    res.json("test done")
})

app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    const {name,email,password} = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.create({            /*User = usermodel   userDoc = user created user*/
        name,
        email,
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password,bcryptSalt),

    }) 


    res.json(userDoc)
})


app.listen(3000);
```

**Register Page**

```
function registerUser(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register',{
            name,
            email,
            password
        }, {
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
  });
    }
```

Comment: It again say the same stuff POST http://localhost:3000/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  ,   xhr.js:154 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}